# How to connect to SQL database from another website?

Tags: php, mysql

Could I have my php scripts on website A and connect to the MySQL database on website B?

If yes, how it would be done? Thanks in advance

```
<?php

$server = "";
$user="";
$pass="";
$dbname="";

$con = mysqli_connect($server,$user,$pass,$dbname);

if(!$con){
   die("Error Connecting with DataBase");
}
```

Comment: This is not secure.

Comment: Wow, I can see you have tried so much already,

Comment: Yes you can, just use database credentials  from Website B and make sure you've remote mysql enabled on Website B google it you'll find the answer

Comment: I think you mean you want to connect to another mysql server, not a website. You already have the connection script, just fill in the details (the 4 variables)

Comment: You need the user and password from the website where is located the mysql database. Once you have it, you can connect if the user has got the aproppiate privileges.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you just need to specify the server in the same way you would specify "localhost" when connecting to a local dbs.  It goes without saying you will need a valid login and password to the remote dbs with the required privilages.

You will also need to configure the remote MySQL server to accept remote connections (this is turned off by default) in my.conf.